# Is is possible to change the name of the w3wp.exe per application pool?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, w3wp

Is is possible to change the name of the w3wp.exe for a certain application pool? I'm using IIS 7.5 of Windows 7.

When I start debugging it is really hard to distinguish between processes (as all of them are called w3wp.exe). It would be very nice if I could change the name of the process.

This is what I see in my Visual Studio:

[image]

Comment: May I ask why you want that? Maybe this helps: http://forums.iis.net/t/1156056.aspx

Comment: I don't think so, but why? Are you trying to distinguish between running IIS applications somehow?

Comment: Similar question at: http://forums.iis.net/t/1166629.aspx

Comment: i guess you already know the work around for this but renaming is not possible

Comment: I use Visual Studio to debug and it is very hard to distinguish between items... check the image.

Comment: you can see that some processes are in session 1, so not yours (you are in session 0 most probably). also you can see that the .net runtime is loaded in the top 2 processes (listed in 'type' column including the version). this should narrow it down a bit.

Comment: In the case illustrated, I would have thought that the fact that one is .NET 2 and the other is .NET 4 would be enough to tell you which one you're using...

Comment: @Menahem, Vista onwards means that the user will be in Session 1 or higher. All `w3wp` processes would be operating in Session 0.

Comment: @Rob - thanks for the update. since he is using 7.5, shouldn't w3wp be in his session ?

Comment: @Menahem, everything runs on session 0. Is this instance I've got 2 w3wp.exe projects, because I disabled the other apps / app pools. I've got at least 10 projects running in 5 separate app pools.

Comment: @Menahem, not if it's running under **IIS**, that's a System service. Perhaps you're thinking of **IIS Express** which is the User Mode equivalent? (And would be the better option in this scenario!) =)

Comment: @Rob, yes i as referring to Express when i wrote 7.5. Kees, maybe you can select them all then click attach ? it should't pose a problem to be attached to more processes than you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading the discussion, the answer is: **no, you can't**.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:
Go in IIS Manager and find your app pool. Right click on it and choose Advanced Settings. Change Identity (under Process Model section) to ApplicationPoolIdentity.

http://prntscr.com/b1yf6m